# Mysterious declaration in Oracle PL/SQL code

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

What means this `&n` declaration in Oracle PL/SQL? Usage in code sample (taken from [here](http://www.way2tutorial.com/plsql/plsql_user_named_exception.php)) is shown below:

```
DECLARE
    myex EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(myex,-20015); 
    n NUMBER := &n;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
        dbms_output.put.line(i);
        IF i=n THEN
            RAISE myex;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN myex THEN
        dbms_output.put.line('loop is end');
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&n` is a [substitution variable](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables.php).

> When a substitution variable is used in a statement, SQL*Plus requests an input value and rewrites the statement to include it. The rewritten statement is passed to the database. As a result, the database server knows nothing of the substitution variable.

Comment: Thank you for brief and accurate explanation.